# Congrats sfdcfox!

Tags: discussion, reputation, recognition

I've just noticed @sfdcfox has just hit 100k rep here on SFSE!

I can say personally he's helped myself amongst countless others and achieving that milestone doesn't come without great advice, answers and persistence.

Thanks for your dedication! Here's to the next 100k!

Comment: Hey, that's part of what makes him such a great Salesforce MVP! Like you Poet, I've learned a great deal from him as well. Congrats @sfdcfox! Very impressive and Kudos to you!

Comment: I can personally say that without @sfdcfox, I would be 10% the SFDC man I am today.  Such elegance in answers, such concise code samples. Whoever employs him should double his salary. Next stop 1M

Comment: Truly amazing. He is helping not only for my questions, but for answers as well. He is politely adding the extra whenever someone post a correct answer. That's the maturity. Congratz centurion!

Comment: Congrats - ditto all of the above, thanks for all the help!

Comment: And this will likely be our first `Great Question` on Meta. Nice. 100 votes for 100k.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Thanks, Poet! I've really enjoyed helping out as much as I can; this milestone is only a reflection of my passion for the platform and helping people. I'm looking forward to the next 100k, and earning badges in new areas as I learn more about Lightning, Marketing Cloud, and so on. While I may have helped a lot of people, a lot of people have also helped me, challenging me to learn and research new things, and for that I'm very grateful. This is a wonderful community, and only getting better as time goes by. You all mean a lot to me, and I'm glad I've been able to help so many of you succeed.

Comment: Congratulations! ~1.7m customers served. At [200,000 rep Jon Skeet got a painting of Unicorns](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/). Just saying, something to aspire to :)

Comment: Crazy good work!

Comment: Thanks for all your support,help and advice.

Comment: Congrats sfdcfox.. :-)

Comment: Congrats @sfdcfox. You helped everyone here in very well manner. The way you answer, i learned a lot from them. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Way to go sfdcfox!

Comment: Congrats and thanks @ sfdcfox

Comment: Congrats sfdcfox, I personally learning a lot from you.

Comment: You are the reason I can call myself a "Saleforce Developer" today, so thank you! Here's 10 more points :P

Comment: Many Congratulations @sfdcfox, Thanks a lot for your support and help. You are truly amazing, Hats off !

Comment: Congrats sfdcfox. Take a bow!!!!

Comment: Congrats dude :)

Comment: Hats off :) Congrats Man..

Comment: Congrats @sfdcfox ! And thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Congrats, well earned indeed! A personal favorite: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41142/error-on-uninstalling-package-via-apex/41155#41155

Comment: Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Congratulations & Thank you for all your help!!

Comment: Congrats sfdcfox

Comment: Congrats buddy :)

Comment: Congrats Brian!

Comment: Congrats and well deserved! Even I have benefited many times from your posts across the sfdc universe.

Comment: Thanks you @sfdcfox for all your help. You are an inspiration.

Comment: Congratulations Brian. You are an inspiration for all. Thanks for all your hard work and helping us out here.

Comment: Major congratulations, I think everybody on here has learnt something from you at some point! All the best.

Comment: Some trivia: @sfdcfox has been a community expert for so long, he also contributed code and support to what was one of the first APAC submissions to the appexchange. I dont even remember how many years ago that was now! A legend!

Comment: Oh @sfdcfox, I'm late for the party, but you very well know how many times you helped me, and I certainly wouldn't be here if it wasn't for you. Or, at least it would take way longer, with a less precise code. 

Thank you for all your help, your dedication and effort to share your knowledge and build a strong community! Kudos to you, sir! Congrats!

Comment: Congrats sfdcfox! You're a Hero for so many of us :)

Answer (score 10):

Thanks. To say you've inspired me to give back more to the community is an understatement. You completely redefined "to the best of my ability" for me personally as an active participant on this exchange, and your sage advice has been welcome each time it was offered. I feel lucky to have someone so even-keeled and prolific to emulate, and even aspire to (delusions of grandeur aside).

I know rep isn't everything, but just to illustrate the point, you've been in the top 3 users every month but one since July 2013, including *most* rep 23 of those intervening 38 months. Talk about dedication!

Answer (score 7):

Congrats sfdcfox.. You are a Legend :-)

Comment: [Not quite yet](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary). Though surely he will be the first!

Answer (score 4):

Like many, I owe him a huge 'thank you' for his help all the time. Congratulations!

Answer (score 4):

Congrats sfdcfox. You are the best.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats sfdcfox. You are the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the first answer from @sfdcfox which got the ball rolling (which became a boulder and a mountain) :)

[what SF features are subject to regulation?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11700/what-sf-features-are-subject-to-regulation/12539#12539)

One other individual I remember when I see @sfdcfox posts is Tom Kyte on Oracle [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1::::RP::) site. He is a legend for his veracity and depth of knowledge in Oracle DB.

You are our Tom Kyte.

Answer (score 0):

Still waiting on your book to be published @sfdcfox