# Promotional Bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've seen this behavior on some other exchanges, where users will offer a bounty on a question simply because the answer is good and deserves more rep. Here's one [extreme example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster). Perhaps this behavior is simply less common here because we don't have as many high rep users. Just for a comparison with Science Fiction & Fantasy:

```
========================================
Rep        |  SciFi Users  |  SFSE Users
----------------------------------------
100,000+   |            3  |           1
50,000+    |           15  |           2
25,000+    |           38  |           6
10,000+    |          100  |          32
========================================
Badge      |  SciFi Users  |  SFSE Users
----------------------------------------
Legendary  |            6  |           0
Epic       |           17  |           2
========================================
```

That difference is...stark, so I can see why there might be fewer users on here who feel like they have reputation to "spare" and bandy about on bounties. We don't even have double digit users who can offer such bounties without losing any `Privileges`. We don't even have plural users with six figures! Actually last week we didn't even have any ([congrats again](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/congrats-sfdcfox)).

- **Are there other reasons we don't award "promotional bounties"? Do we think it's kosher?**
- **When offering a "promotional bounty", is it cool to run it for the entire duration to draw more attention?**

See also the last reason on this list:

[image: Bounty Reasons]

> **Reward existing answer**
>   One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

Comment: I can't find any reference to a promotional bounty in [Help]. Do you have a link that explains exactly what they are or would you please edit your post to elaborate on what they are and how they different from a regular bounty?

Comment: I pulled a screenshot of the bounty reasons from [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210861/bounties-how-to-categorize-the-reason) and added it to the question to better illustrate.

Comment: You're referring to the last item on the list at the bottom? Oh, I see where you have it in grey. Thank you for the clarification, Adrian. Well, anyone can put up a question for a bounty. Doesn't need to be either the asker or the person marked with the correct answer. I've put bounties on other ppls questions that didn't have answers before.

Comment: I'd never noticed that last option before... I've offered bounties on a couple of questions where new users have erroneously raised a flag along the lines of "please help!" but they've asked a genuinely good question and gotten nothing but crickets.

Note: DO NOT raise saying "please help" in the hopes that I'll offer bounty... it's rare. Just ask a good question instead.

Comment: From the other side of things, are we sure that there are enough high quality answers that deserve an after the fact bounty award? Maybe due to just the subject matter of this board (professional vs. a personal passion like sci fi) people just aren't inclined to be grateful enough for the answers to part with their own points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one has answered this question, so I'm going to go ahead and try it. If there's backlash, so be it, but if anyone cares enough about how Stack Exchange is supposed to work to be upset at how I use the bounty system, they probably should participate more in Meta. :)